# Getting dynamic output using JSONata while entering value and sample data in UI

Tags: javascript, jsonata

[I try to pass the dynamic input value to JSONata but it is not taking it in line:15 I am using $add() in which I am assigning input value to it but it is not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QcBb.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>JSONata test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonata/jsonata.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function greeting() {
        var json = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("json").value);
        var query = document.getElementById("query").value;
        var expression = jsonata("$add()");
        expression.registerFunction("add", () => query);

        var result = expression.evaluate(json);
        document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = result;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="json">{ "name": "Wilbur" }</textarea>
    <textarea id="query">name</textarea>
    <button onclick="greeting()">Click me</button>
    <p id="greeting"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

`I am creating $add() function inside JSONata method and return dynamic input value but it is not giving desired output.`

`As of now I am getting whatever I am passing inside field but what I need is when I pass key for Ex:"name" I should get that value using jsonata expression. I need output same as what JSONata method returns`

`Let me know If I need to provide any other information`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is because your `$add()` function is written to return the query itself, not the evaluated value of the query.

The parameters need to be passed in on the evaluation line and the body of your function needs to handle the evaluated result e.g.:

```
// Change: Note the passing of the textbox query as a param
var expression = jsonata(`$add(${query})`); 
// Change: Using evaluated param as output
expression.registerFunction("add", (a) => `Hello ${a}!`);
```

You can see this described in the [documentation's example of `registerFunction`](https://docs.jsonata.org/embedding-extending#expressionregisterfunctionname-implementation-signature):

> var expression = jsonata("$add(61, 10005)");
> expression.registerFunction("add", (a, b) => a + b, "<nn:n>");
>
> expression.evaluate({}); // 10066

Working example: https://codepen.io/scarabaeus/pen/OJxJbXp?editors=1000